# elastic search grok filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I'v just started to work with ELK and logstash
I want to parse my apache custom log
I wrote simple logstash pipeline

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
}
filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I tried with `match => { "message" => "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}" }`

but it doesn't parse correct my log

Example of my log

```
10.7.46.39 - - [25/Feb/2021:18:17:08 +0300] "POST /secure/TvmGw6 HTTP/1.1" 200 332
10.4.14.39 - - [25/Feb/2021:18:17:08 +0300] "POST /secure/TvmGw6 HTTP/1.1" 200 332
```

Could you help me to write correct filter. Thanks

Comment: Whats the output that configuration is generating?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Grok Pattern that matches your log:

`%{IP:iPad dress} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATH:path} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:bytes}`

I have used the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to validate the grik pattern.